# Is the Stay Puft brand brought into any other films?

Tags: props

Many directors or writers keep using brands in other movies they make.

Such examples include Abrams with the Slusho brand and Tarantino Red Apple cigarettes. Also many brands are used only in fiction to replace known brands, Spyder Fynder instead of Google.

I'm wondering if the Stay Puft brand has shown up in any other movies since Ghostbusters?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know if Stay  Puft has been in any other shows but I doubt it since [it's now a real world product.](http://www.thinkgeek.com/caffeine/candy/e59b/)

[image: Stay Puft]

While not a brand the [Tangiers Casino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangier_%28disambiguation%29) has appeared in the movie [Casino.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112641/)  It has also appeared on TV on CSI as one of [Sam Braun's casinos,](http://csi.wikia.com/wiki/Sam_Braun) and in an episode of [Bones.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0869544/)

Comment: Seriously, the marshmallows are square? That is just wrong, but now I want to try one more than ever!

Answer (score 4):

According to Wikipedia, Stay Puft returned in the cartoon Ghostbusters series "The Real Ghostbusters".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stay_Puft_Marshmallow_Man

Comment: As well as the sequel films and reboot nonsense; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stay_Puft_Marshmallow_Man#:~:text=In%20the%20reboot%20film%20Ghostbusters%20(2016)%2C%20which%20sets%20in%20another%20narrative%20universe